# Generic enum type in php

Tags: php, types, enums

How can I specify an argument type to take **any** enum value?

Something like `function processEnum(enum $value)` would be ideal, however nothing seems to exist?

```php
enum Numbers: int {
  case FIRST = 1;
  case SECOND = 2;
}


enum Foo: string {
  case BAR = 'bar';
}

function printEnum($enumValue) {
  echo $enumValue->value;
}

printEnum(Numbers::FIRST); // 1
printEnum(Foo::BAR); // 'bar'
printEnum('fail'); // I want to reject this!
```

Additionally it would be nice to separate backed vs non-backed enums or additionally backed types; enums that are backed as strings for example.

Comment: Like [the UnitEnum interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unitenum.php)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All enums implement [the `UnitEnum` interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unitenum.php), and backed enums (those with a type and a `->value` property) also implement [the `BackedEnum` interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.backedenum.php). You can write type constraints for those:

```
enum Numbers: int {
  case FIRST = 1;
  case SECOND = 2;
}
enum Foo: string {
  case BAR = 'bar';
}
enum Something {
   case WHATEVER;
}

function doSomething(UnitEnum $enumValue) {
  echo "blah\n";
}
function printEnum(BackedEnum $enumValue) {
  echo $enumValue->value, "\n";
}

doSomething(Numbers::FIRST); // blah
doSomething(Foo::BAR); // blah
doSomething(Something::WHATEVER); // blah
doSomething('fail'); // TypeError

printEnum(Numbers::FIRST); // 1
printEnum(Foo::BAR); // 'bar'
printEnum(Something::WHATEVER); // TypeError
printEnum('fail'); // TypeError
```

Answer (score 0):

Version one with interfaces

```
<?php
interface MyEnums {} 

enum Numbers : int implements MyEnums {
  case FIRST = 1;
  case SECOND = 2;
}


enum Foo : string implements MyEnums{
  case BAR = 'bar';
}

function printEnum(MyEnums $enumValue) {
  echo $enumValue->value;
}

printEnum(Numbers::FIRST); // 1
printEnum(Foo::BAR); // 'bar'
printEnum('fail'); // Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: printEnum(): Argument #1 ($enumValue) must be of type MyEnums
```

Version two with exception, but will also take any class with public property 'value'

```
<?php

enum Numbers : int {
  case FIRST = 1;
  case SECOND = 2;
}


enum Foo : string {
  case BAR = 'bar';
}

function printEnum($enumValue) {
  echo $enumValue->value ?? throw new Exception('Rejected');
}

printEnum(Numbers::FIRST); // 1
printEnum(Foo::BAR); // 'bar'
printEnum('fail'); // throws an exception
```